# Parse.Promise deprecated/removed from type definitions?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

While migrating a Project from parse 1.x.x to the latest version of Parse Server I see that the type definitions for `Parse.Promise` has gone. I need to update this line of code and just wondering if any Parse Platform veterans have any experience on what this can be updated to in terms of the latest version of Parse Server to modernize my app?

```
    Parse.Promise.prototype.always = function (callback: any) {
        return this.always(callback)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse Server 3.0.0 uses the 2.0.0 JS SDK which has removed `Parse.Promise` in favour of native promises.

You can take a look at the guide for [upgrading to 2.0.0 of the JS SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/master/2.0.0.md) which gives examples of how to migrate to native promises.

You may also want to take a look at guide for [upgrading to 3.0.0 of Parse Sever](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/3.0.0.md).